# Why mainWindow is null if I invoke it from the menu?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm invoking the same IBAction from 2 different xib files (the main window and the main menu).

```
- (IBAction)showEditor:(id)sender
{
 ...    [document mainWindow]; 
}
```

However, mainWindow is null when I invoke showEditor from the menu. But i don't understand:bBoth xib files are initialized when the apps starts, so everything should be initialized when I click on the menu item.

thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Both xib files are initialized when the apps starts" ? How to initialize the xib files ?

Comment: @Laurent Etiemble The project is not mine, and I can't find how they are initialized (I see them already on the screen). But I suspect they are initialized when the respective classes (specified in the Class Identity field in the Interface Builder Inspector panel) are initialized.

Comment: What object holds the `document` outlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `document` is also null? That would explain why `[document mainWindow]` is null. See if your two instances of `document` are the same.

Comment: Ya, the document is also null. The code is the same, but maybe importing the same class into 2 different xibs creates 2 different instances ?